# What is Log Collector and how it works?

Tags: android

What is a Log Collector an how does it works? Please help me out in understanding this.

Answer (score 1):

Collects output of logcat and sends it to a developer using email or messaging. Can be used as a standalone application or invoked through the intent API by another application.

check this also for an example http://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/downloads/detail?name=android-log-collector-1.1.0.apk

Comment: But this is an application that should be downloaded.

Comment: @Richa: yes download and run that app so that you will get a clear idea abt hw it works

Comment: heyy I downloaded the application but I am not able to execute it..plz help me out! How shall I execute the application in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

It's a component that would store some logging informations, generally in order to send them to a remote location *(by email, http request, ...)*.

For an example you can take a look at the following project : [android-log-collector](https://code.google.com/p/android-log-collector/).

On android, "log" generally corresponds to the [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html).